# Application configuration from database, cast value from string

Tags: c#, configuration

In an existing c# project I need get configuration parameters from datatase. In this database entry are Key, Value, valueType where valueType can be S (for string), B (for boolean), I (for integer) etc...
Value field is a string. How I can get a cast value from db? I need to create method that automatically return value in correct type.

Thanks.

Comment: Create a switch statement and use the TryParse methods for each type

Comment: "S" for `string`, `sbyte` and `short`? Sounds like you may want to reconsider your requirements.

Comment: Thanks. I can't reconsider requirements because is a real application.

Comment: Thanks. I can use a switch statement but what about the type of return value?

Comment: You can do two things -

1- If you know what type would be returned in which case use dynamic as return type.
2- Set the return type to object and then you will have to cast to the desired type when the function will be called.

Comment: Thanks. There are two solutions, but return I don't like return an object, or return dynamic. It's not type-safe.